# Book reference request for statistical reliability theory

Tags: references, reliability

I'm about to learn **statistical reliability theory** for the first time. I'm told that **Barlow and Proschan**'s book entitled **"Statistical theory of reliability and life testing"** is a classic on this topic. However the book is age-old and also I cannot find a copy of it.

**I was wondering if anyone can suggest me an alternative (or a list of alternative) decent book(s)/monograph(s)/lecture note(s) from which I can learn the subject (basics and advanced). **

Comment: check out this site it will helps you a lot.
**"https://weibull.com"**

Comment: Thanks for the references therein +1 It gives a list of books. However, which one suits my purpose is not entirely clear. I'm still keeping the question open for recommendations from the readers.

Comment: If you are looking for basic concept then **Life Data Analysis** is very suitable.

Comment: The part that was posted as an answer (a bare link) has been converted to a comment. The part that should have been an answer (an actual book title) was posted as a comment. I invite you to convert that to a full reference and repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Reliability: Probabilistic Models and Statistical Methods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0692000275) by Lawrence M. Leemis. It is a great value at ~$34 for the 366 pages.  I'm told the author got sick of big textbook companies pricing things at outrageous price points.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for basic concept then **Life Data Analysis** is very suitable. This book is easily available on **"https://weibull.com/"** in pdf.